# How do I make a MPMovieController fullscreen view on top of a UIPopoverController?

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen, uipopovercontroller

I have successfully put a MPMoviePlayerController in a UIPopoverController by doing:

```
NSString *filenameString = [NSString stringWithString:[[helpVideosArray objectAtIndex:tagNumber] objectForKey:VIDEO_FILE_NAME]];
HelpVideoPopover *helpVideoPopover = [[HelpVideoPopover alloc] initWithVideoFilename:filenameString PreviewFrameView:self];
currentPopover = [[[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:helpVideoPopover] retain] autorelease];
[currentPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 240)];
[currentPopover presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton*)sender).frame inView:previewView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
currentPopover.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:((HelpVideoPopover*)[currentPopover contentViewController]).movieController.view];
```

The problem is that when the user wants to view the video fullscreen(and I allow that) that the popover view is on top of the fullscreen video. So my question is that is there another I'm supposed to be doing this. Or maybe when I display the popover I just use a blank one and overlay a movie player on top of it from the parent view controller? I would really like to keep the movie player logic inside the popover view controller though.

Comment: I'm having the same problem now. I posted in the Apple developer forums with no response. Was there a solution? Maybe closing the popover and creating a new MPMoviePlayer to go fullscreen once the popover is closed, then reopen it when full screen exits?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your application i would imagine you could do this in several ways.

You could either open the video in a fullscreen modal view - This would cover the popover.
If you're displaying the fullscreen video in the detail-view behind the popover, then you could do something as simple as just hiding the popover once the fullscreen video has been shown.